# Link to scroll to top not working

Tags: javascript, html

I can not figure out why this is not giving me an animation. It goes to the top of the page like it supposed to but there is no animation. Can someone help me find out why?

here id the javascript code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: target_top }, 600);
    return false;
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body id="top">
```

and here is the link that i need to perform the scroll.

```
<td><a href="#top" class="scrollup">Back to Top</a></td>
```

again, it goes to the top of the page but there is no animation.

edit here is the entire html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body id="top">
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="title">Name</div>
        <div id="tagline">Web Designer + Programmer</div>
      <div id="navbar">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#services">Services</a></td><td><a href="#about">About</a></td><td><a href="#contact">Contact</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="servicescontent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="aboutcontent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="services2">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="services2content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="contactinfo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="copyright">Copyright 2013</div>
        <div id="footernavbar">
            <table style="font-size: 16px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#about">About</a></td><td><a href="#services">Services</a></td><td><a href="#top" class="scrollup">Back to Top</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its fairly unconventional to id your body. Also, you should add a </script> to your jquery and start your script under a new tag to be tidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@skidadon is correct, 0 will probably solve it. But you've also got some incorrectly formatted script tags. You need a separate tag for Jquery and a separate one for the code you're running. It might also help to use `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your event handler. Here's a simple edit of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.scrollup').click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body id="top">

    <div style="height: 900px">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="scrollup">go to top</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It's not target_top, it's 0

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: sorry but that did not work. still no animation :( thank you for the input though

Comment: i promise i did everything that he did in fiddle. still no animation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nn9Zq/

Because your script tag has a src and inner content the behavior can't really be predicted. so it was reverting to normal jump anchor behavior.  To remedy this, as Gary said break it into two script tags.